# Amplifier volume potentiometer causes voltage offset

Tags: arduino, amplifier, potentiometer

Using [answer about microphone](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/36809/18643) I have built a simple amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzw9Yz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I changed some of the parts due to my needs and resources.

- **R1**: is now potentiometer and allows me to set the "0" of the sound to 2.5V
- **R3**: should control amplification (but it doesn't seem to), so again a potentiometer
- **C1**: unless the original answer meant electrolytic capacitor, there's no way to get 22uF capacitor. So I used just two 22nF caps.
- **C2**: I have 10uF capacitor (salvaged from old sound card ironically), so I used that

So I have set up R1 to get 2.5 volts on silence. The image displays 80Hz sine wave rather than silence, [I generated it here (works on Android)](http://onlinetonegenerator.com/).

[image: image description]

Now if I move the **R3.2**, instead of change to gain, I just get voltage offset, and an insignificant one. Picture describes full range (min - max - min) of that particular potentiometer:

[image: image description]

Note also that **increasing resistance increases voltage on output**.

I could use my 50k potentiometer instead but that would give me no precision.

So what is wrong with my circuit? How to control the amplification?

**Note:** I displayed the analog input using [this processing script](http://pastebin.com/ENvYtsHe) and [this arduino program](http://pastebin.com/s3f4G00t), both mine but I thought I might share.

Comment: AFAIK this circuit has a fixed gain. No gain control is available. It wholly depends on the voltage/current produced by the mic. Also, try moving your question to the start, as it got buried at the end.

Comment: Also your values seem odd. The R3 is 36k, to R4 1k? That would be 0.14V center, not 2.5V.

Comment: And Oli recommended C1 to be 1µF or greater. A 1uf ceramic would be fine.

Comment: Oh, essentially to change the gain without the offset change, R3 and R4 need to be changed, proportionally, lower.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

- Remove R1 the way it is currently wired and all wires leading to it.
- Connect a ~1k resistor from Vcc to the transistor collector.
- Connect R1's end leads from the transistor collector to ground, respectively. A larger value for R1 might be a good idea, such as 10k, but it isn't critical.
- Connect a 1µF ceramic cap from R1's wiper to the arduino.

**Edit:**

- Also connect a 10k from Vcc to the arduino pin, and a 10k from that to ground. This will cause the output to center around 2.5v, which seems to be what you are after.

This way, the position of R1 forms a "tap" between full signal, and no signal. Then adjust R3's value to give the cleanest output with the loudest microphone signal expected. There is a technical term for adjusting these resistor values - [biasing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211500/how-are-the-resistor-values-r1-and-r2-calculated-for-a-transistor-amplifier-that). Also [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64777/bjt-bias-design-and-operating/64789#64789). Have you calculated what the values should be?

Comment: No, I didn't calculate anything. I just adjusted till it looked nice on the graph.

Comment: I think R4 needs to be larger, like was shown in your previous link. And C4 needs to be much larger like Passerby and Oli suggested. But you're very close.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll buy some tomorow and come back to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your gain will be approximately $$a=-\dfrac{R1}{R2}$$
As you modulate the base voltage, the emitter voltage will increase by a roughly equal amount.  This increases the current through R1.  Almost all the current through R1 also flows through R2, causing a voltage drop.

After choosing the gain you want for your circuit, you'll need to adjust the bias using R3 to maintain your 2.5V zero point.

$$V_e = \dfrac{2.5V\cdot R2}{R1}$$
$$V_b = V_e + 0.7V$$
$$V_b = \dfrac{V_{cc}\cdot R4}{R3 + R4}$$

One more thing to keep in mind is the size of your 44nF capacitor.  It will create a highpass filter with cutoff frequency 
$$f_c = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\cdot (R4||R3)\cdot c_1}$$
With the current values you have in there this comes out to be over 3kHz.  You can hear much lower than that so I recommend choosing a larger capacitor.

Comment: What's the $(R4||R3)$?

Comment: The parallel combination of R3 and R4.  R3*R4/(R3+R4)